# Attempting to run a function when Google Maps Marker is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, parse-platform

I am attempting to run a function that will play a video when a marker on google maps is tapped however I cannot get that function to run although there are no errors.  Perhaps there is an issue with my logic or control flow.  Below is my view controller as well as the function.

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!

var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?

var url : NSURL?
var videoData : NSData?
var doUpload : Bool?
var FriendsOrPublic : String?
var dataPath : String?
var gmsPlace : GMSPlace?
var gpsCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    //placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    var gmsPlace : GMSPlace?
    let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient()
    placesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback { (placeLikelihoods, error) -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoods = placeLikelihoods {
            for likelihood in placeLikelihoods.likelihoods {
                gmsPlace = likelihood.place
                //print("Current Place name \(gmsPlace.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                //print("Current Place address \(gmsPlace.formattedAddress)")
                //print("Current Place attributions \(gmsPlace.attributions)")
                //print("Current PlaceID \(gmsPlace.placeID)")
                self.gpsCoordinates = (gmsPlace!.coordinate)

            }
            //print(self.gpsCoordinates)

        }
    }
    let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Object has been saved.")
    }

    print(url)
    print(videoData)
    print(doUpload)
    print(FriendsOrPublic)
    print(dataPath)
    if doUpload == true {
        Upload()
    }

    Download()
    viewMap.delegate = self

}

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    //print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    gpsCoordinates = locValue
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(gpsCoordinates!, zoom: 16.9)
    //let camera = GMSCamera
    print(camera)
    viewMap.camera = camera
    viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
    viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = false


    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = self.gpsCoordinates!
    marker.title = "Newport Beach"
    marker.snippet = "California"
    marker.map = viewMap
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
var marker : GMSMarker!
func Download() {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"UploadedVideoCurrent")

    //        query.whereKey("GPS", equalTo: "ChIJTbSOh8Pf3IARt311y2Wqspc")
    query.whereKey("typeofPost", equalTo: "Public")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) coordinates.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectForKey("GPS"))
                    let postsLat = object.objectForKey("GPS")!.latitude as Double
                    let postsLong = object.objectForKey("GPS")!.longitude as Double
                    let position: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: postsLat, longitude:postsLong)

                    self.marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                    self.marker.map = self.viewMap
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
func viewMap(viewMap: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker)
{
    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to play the video, I don't see a code which plays video in the above snippet. To play the video write a method which plays the video and invoke that method from the didTapMarker delegate method of GMSMapView, as of now you're just printing "tapped" in that method.

Comment: @iamyogish In the future I am planning on playing the video, my problem is that that function is not running at all, as the print statement never runs.

Comment: Could you just print out the delegate property of the viewMap object at the end of the didUpdateLocations method and check whether the delegate is still your ViewController or not? I suspect that it could be the case where delegate isn't set at appropriate place or it is getting changed.

Comment: @iamyogish the print statement never runs inside of my didUpdateLocations either

Comment: are you getting a prompt when you install the app ? Asking for your permission to access your location ??

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong delegate function. you should still call the function "mapView" because that's how the delegate function is defined, even though your map itself is declared as "viewMap"

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker!) -> Bool {
       print("tapped")
}
```